# "In" code not recognizedin Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have copy pasted some code from a tutorial but when I arrived here:

```
azimuth = Math.round(azimuth.toFloat())
    compass_image.rotation = (-azimuth).toFloat()

    val where = when(azimuth){
        in 281...348 -> "NW"
        in 281...348 -> "NW"
        in 281...348 -> "NW"
        in 281...348 -> "NW"
        in 281...348 -> "NW"
        in 281...348 -> "NW"
        in 281...348 -> "NW"
        else -> "N"
    }

    view_degree.text = "$azimuth° $where"
```

Android Studio failed to recognize the command "in"... How come?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have to use two dots instead of three to express ranges. Furthermore, all those cases are equal so it's useless to repeat them.

```kotlin
val where = when(azimuth){
    in 281..348 -> "NW"
    else -> "N"
}
```

Additional info here: [kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html)

Comment: Additional info in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html

Comment: @MichielLeegwater thanks, i've added it to the answer.